# Ampersand character as value in data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

Is it possible to have '&' character as an attribute value in the data extension? I am using SQL Query activity to insert the value.

Or is there a better way then my current SQL code.  I've tried using the actual '&' and the ascii character like below.  I realise that it is not possible to have the ':' in the SQL code.

```
select
case
        when B.Contact_Email is not null 
            then STUFF (
                (select ' ' + CHAR(38) + ' ' + A.Contact_First_Name
                from [some DE] A
                where A.Contact_Email = B.Contact_Email and A.OpportunityId = B.OpportunityId
                group by A.OpportunityId
                FOR XML PATH('')),1,7,'')
        else B.Contact_First_Name
    end as 'Contact_First_Name',
from
   [Some DE]
```

Is there another method that I can use?  The purpose of this is to merge the identical email rows into one row.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FOR XML translates & to `&amp;`. This works as intended as XML does not support the & character.

You could use a placeholder for the delimiter such as pipe (|). And then use the REPLACE function to replace the placeholder with the & character.

```
select
case
        when B.Contact_Email is not null 
            then REPLACE(STUFF (
                (select ' | ' + A.Contact_First_Name
                from [some DE] A
                where A.Contact_Email = B.Contact_Email and A.OpportunityId = B.OpportunityId
                group by A.OpportunityId
                FOR XML PATH('')),1,3,''), '|', '&')
        else B.Contact_First_Name
    end as 'Contact_First_Name',
from
   [Some DE]
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mentioned that I want to avoid having "&amp;" HTML code inserted in the data extension value.  Is there a way to override this?  The code above will put the value as "firstname &amp; firstname" as a value

Comment: So if you write *SELECT a.FirstName + ' & ' + b.firstName FROM TableA a, TableB b* it saves it as *firstname &amp; firstname*? When I run this query, the attribute value gets saved as *firstname & firstname*

Comment: Yes that's what I got _firstname &amp; firstname_.  Perhaps is it because of the STUFF that turns it into XML prior to loading to Data Extension?

Comment: Did some quick testing. And as you say, the FOR XML rewrites *&* to *&amp;*. I am not sure what you want to achieve with the STUFF function here. Try to replace it with the REPLACE function. Where you replace '&amp;' with '&'.

Comment: Thanks for your help thus far.  The purpose of the STUFF function is to combine the contact first name together whenever 2 contact records have the same email address in the one opportunity.  At the very end of the query, I have a partition by function to give me the row number if indeed there are duplicate emails.  I have not find another SQL function that allows me to do this.  Unfortunately though the SQL Query editor will prevent me from typing **";"** as it is a reserved character. Perhaps there is another function similar to STUFF that doesn't require me to use FOR XML?

Comment: @Yopz updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so so very much!  did a quick test and it's working! I never thought of this angle.